# save plot from graphics device 2 in Rstudio does not work

Tags: rstudio

Somebody could tell why saving this  graph blocks Rstudio?

```
 windows(width=7, height=7, pointsize=25,xpinch = 600,ypinch = 600)
 par(oma=c(0,0,0,0))
 par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
 plot(seq(1,10,1),seq(1,10,1))

 sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you see any errors in the R console when attempting to save the file? What file format are you attempting to save to?

Comment: png, metafile, eps...The problem seems to be here: xpinch = 600,ypinch = 600, whenever I set the resolution below 100, it works. A pity we cannot plot at higher resolutions in RStudio.